# Get contacts without ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I Want to get the contacts on the device without using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, it is possible in objective-c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Below there's a simple snippet of code that do the work:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

CFArrayRef allPeopleRef = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, nil, kABPersonSortByFirstName);

CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);


for( int i = 0 ; i < nPeople ; i++ ) {
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeopleRef, i );
    CFStringRef tmpStringRef = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty); 
    NSLog(@"FirstName: %@", (NSString *)tmpStringRef);
    CFRelease(tmpStringRef);
}

//clean up memory
CFRelease(allPeopleRef);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

For more details, please refer to the Apple Developer Documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1).

Comment: This code helps me to save lot of time..Thanks and +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

It is. Please refer to the AddresBook programming guide. [Direct interaction section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1).